# values cannot be entered for List<String> in create page of grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

This is the domain class:

```
package com.sample

class Person {
       String id
       String name
       Integer age
       Address address
       List children
  static hasMany = [pets:Pet, children: String, aliases : Alias]

  static mapWith = "mongo"
  static constraints = {
           address nullable:true
  }
}
```

This is the the create page of the app:

[image: create page of the app]]

Can someone please tell me how I can get a list to write in the create Person page and a list editable in the edit Person page. (I'm using generated views by the command grails generate-view com.sample.Person)

Comment: Make childrens as ENUM

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `List children` in domain class. But I'm not sure if grails supports scaffolding for relations with basic non-domain types (`String` in your case). If removing the list wouldn't help you will need to handle this situation manually.